# how to get rotation matrix from quaternion in python

Tags: python, ros-kinetic, quaternion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can see tf.transformations have a matrix to quaternion function, but is there a way to do the opposite in python?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/324354/how-to-get-rotation-matrix-from-quaternion-in-python/) by [mugetsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/1134/mugetsu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 195 on 2019-05-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you can import tf.transformations and use the many functions defined there
the code itself can be found [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/code/transformations.py.html)

```
from tf.transformations import quaternion_matrix
matrix = quaternion_matrix([1, 0, 0, 0])
```

Just be careful for what you type in, I think the order here if you use a quaternion from a ros message would be [quat.w, quat.x, quat.y, quat.z]

EDIT: the version coming with ROS Kinetic is quite old and uses the input [quat.x, quat.y, quat.z, quat.w], the updated version on the link uses the reversed input shown above.

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2019-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [`tf.TransformerROS` class](http://docs.ros.org/api/tf/html/python/tf_python.html#transformerros) has a `fromTranslationRotation` method that will turn a translation and quaternion into a 4x4 matrix representation. If you set the translation to zero then it will give you just the rotation in the matrix. The `asMatrix` method is also relevant if you have just the target frame, because it will also do the lookup for you.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2019-05-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1